# Vercel + NextJS: NowBuildError is not defined

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my NextJS application on Vercel but the build always fails with the error `ReferenceError: NowBuildError is not defined`, even though the NextJS application was built successfully. I have reached out to the Vercel support but they can only help me if I make my repository public, which unfortunately is not an option. I have offered them to send them a ZIP-File of the entire project but they didn't take up the offer.

I'm posting this here in the hope that someone has any idea what is causing this error. Any idea is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a repo to reproduce the error: https://github.com/omnibrain/vercel-bug

I've contacted the Vercel support again with this repo. As soon as I get an aswer I will update this question for the next poor soul encountering this error.

Relevant logs of the build:

```
14:39:30.028    info  - Using external babel configuration from /vercel/workpath3/.babelrc
14:39:55.285    info  - Compiled successfully
14:39:55.286    info  - Collecting page data...
14:39:56.273    info  - Generating static pages (0/2)
14:39:56.757    info  - Generating static pages (2/2)
14:39:56.757    info  - Finalizing page optimization...
14:39:56.785    Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
14:39:56.785    ┌ λ /                                                          662 B           299 kB
14:39:56.785    ├   /_app                                                      0 B             146 kB
14:39:56.785    ├ ○ /404                                                       1.21 kB         148 kB
14:39:56.786    ├ ○ /conversation/[conversationId]                             3.31 kB         302 kB
14:39:56.786    └ λ /topic/[topicId]                                           13.2 kB         312 kB
14:39:56.786    + First Load JS shared by all                                  146 kB
14:39:56.786      ├ chunks/ab9efbc8d7cf444f2a1dec397df8d1d8182e9a7f.3290e1.js  23.6 kB
14:39:56.786      ├ chunks/cb0f0b62e252180070876650b5cd91101d837ec4.ec6bad.js  2.17 kB
14:39:56.786      ├ chunks/commons.6e164c.js                                   14.3 kB
14:39:56.786      ├ chunks/ff239f9d.d2e033.js                                  56.4 kB
14:39:56.787      ├ chunks/framework.009b20.js                                 40.5 kB
14:39:56.787      ├ chunks/main.c4bc76.js                                      6.47 kB
14:39:56.787      ├ chunks/pages/_app.08216f.js                                1.59 kB
14:39:56.787      └ chunks/webpack.4cbdc2.js                                   1.22 kB
14:39:56.787    λ  (Lambda)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
14:39:56.787    ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
14:39:56.787    ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
14:39:56.788       (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
14:39:56.788    Next.js Analytics is enabled for this production build. You'll receive a Real Experience Score computed by all of your visitors.
14:39:56.954    Done in 39.89s.
14:40:13.098    Traced Next.js serverless functions for external files in: 16118.239ms
14:40:16.248    Compressed shared serverless function files: 3149.457ms
14:40:16.552    All serverless functions created in: 301.819ms
14:40:28.090    ReferenceError: NowBuildError is not defined
14:40:28.091        at retry.retries (/var/task/sandbox-worker.js:116373:9)
14:40:28.091        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
14:40:28.091        at async patchBuild (/var/task/sandbox-worker.js:116310:10)
14:40:28.091        at async patchBuildToUploading (/var/task/sandbox-worker.js:117471:47)
14:40:28.091        at async /var/task/sandbox-worker.js:116998:39
14:40:32.901    Done with "package.json"
14:40:33.608    Build completed. Populating build cache...
14:41:06.395    Uploading build cache [79.95 MB]...
14:41:11.186    Build cache uploaded: 4791.125ms
14:41:11.419    Done with "api/analytics.ts"
```

Comment: I'm assuming you can't replicate that issue when building locally?

Comment: No, locally I can build and run the project perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug on Vercel's side. They have fixed the bug, now everything works again.